# 3D plot using kernel density, R-cran

Tags: r

I want to see in 3D, a graphic similar to:

[Multivariate Kernel Density](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYndP.png)

This graphic, generated in Matlab by code:

```
clear all  
  % generate synthetic data
  data=[randn(500,2);
      randn(500,1)+3.5, randn(500,1);];
  % call the routine, which has been saved in the current directory 
  [bandwidth,density,X,Y]=kde2d(data);
  % plot the data and the density estimate
  contour3(X,Y,density,50), hold on
  plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'r.','MarkerSize',5)
```

Now, my implementation in R.
Here's my data:

```
xc1 <- matrix(rnorm(200)*0.5+2, 100, 2) 
xc2 <- matrix(rnorm(200)*0.5+4, 100, 2) 
xc <- rbind(xc1,xc2)
```

In future, I will use this logic to generic distribution of data, that's why I want use kde. So:

```
fhat<-kde(x=xc)
```

And using plot:

```
plot(fhat,display="persp")
```

[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFJqd.png)

But, I no understand how this "plot" make it. Viewing fhat, I cannot see xgrid, ygrid, density axes.

I want plot same figure using persp3d, with specific grid:

```
seqi <- seq(0,6,0.1)
seqj <- seq(0,6,0.1)

persp3d(seqi, seqj, z1,col = 'red')
```

How can I obtain z1 with kde ?

Tnx very much for attention

Comment: `demo("bivar",package="rgl")` ...

Comment: Tnx very much for your attention Ben!.
I want use kde, not kde2d to make a generic algorithm. But I use your demo to learn more about 3d plot.
I solved my problem setting xmin and xmax in kde:

`fhat<-kde(x=dados$inputsTrain,xmin = c(0,0), xmax = c(6,6))`

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you can post an answer to your own question (that's encouraged) ...

Comment: @FelipeMouraOliveira Could you update your solution? What is dados$inputsTrain?